# Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $Y_i$ be a $T_B$ compact subspace of $X= Y_1 \cup .....\cup Y_n$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a  topological space and $Y_i$ be a $T_B$ compact subspace of $X= Y_1 \cup .....\cup Y_n$.

> Is $X$ a $T_B$X$ be $ space? if  $X = \bigcup_{i \in I} Y_i$ and $Y_i$ be a $T_B$ compact subspace, will $X$ be  $T_B$ space?if $Y_i$  is only closed, will $X$ be  $T_B$ space?

Comment: What is a $T_B$-space? Can you add the definition?

Comment: @Martin: It’s another name for a $KC$ space, one in which all compact subsets are closed.